# Firebase login failure

Tags: firebase-cli

When I login firebase using "firebase login", it shows these errors:

```
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)

at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: is firebase installed globally on your computer?

Comment: How do I check it.

Comment: @LiZhangTam got to [firebase cli documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-npm)

Comment: Yes it is globally.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?